# JButton call function in other class

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am creating a timer application. I created my timer (in millisecond) and my interface (with JFrame). I would like to start my chrono (in class "Chrono") when I click on bouton "Start_button" (in class "WindowChrono") from my main class "Application".

**Start_button** in **WindowChrono**

```java
JButton Start_button = new JButton("Start");
        Start_button.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        Start_button.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        Start_button.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        Start_button.setBounds(474, 456, 142, 27);
        Start_button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if(i==0) {
                    Start_button.setText("Stop");
                    i = 1;
                }
                else {
                    Start_button.setText("Start");
                    i = 0;
                }
            }
        });
```

**main** in **Application**

```java
public class Application extends WindowChrono {
    
    public void main(String[] args) {
        WindowChrono window = new WindowChrono();
        run();
        Chrono Timer = new Chrono();
        int refreshTime = 10;
        Timer.start(); // LORS DE L ACTIVATION DU BOUTON START
        Timer.stop(); // LORS DE L ACTIVATION DU BOUTON STOP
        while (Timer.getStopTime == 0) {
            Thread.sleep(refreshTime);
            System.out.println(Timer.actualTime()); // AFFICHE LE TEMPS ACUTEL DANS LA FENETRE D'AFFICHAGE
            }
        
        System.out.println(Timer.getTime());
    }
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

First you want to show your window. So in your `main` method you can put this code to start it:

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
           Application window = new Application();  // Application is a WindowChrono because it extends it
           window.setVisible(true);
      }
});
```

It will make sure that Swing handles the appearance of the window as soon as possible (invokeLater). So you don't have to worry about that anymore.

Now, once the window is visible it will take over. All algorithms, methods or what ever you execute should be done in the Window instance (and no longer in your `main`)

So your  `Application` has a constructor somewhere:

```
public class Application extends WindowChrono{

     public Application(){
           // your constructor will be executed when you call "new Application()"
     }
}
```

In your constructor you could initialise your timer (without starting it) so that the "timer" instance exists in your Window.

```
private Chrono timer;

public Application(){
    this.timer = new Chrono();
}
```

Your button is looking good already. Now you only need to start/stop the timer from inside the `ActionListener`:

```
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if(i==0) {
                Start_button.setText("Stop");
                i = 1;
                Application.this.timer.start();
            }
            else {
                Start_button.setText("Start");
                i = 0;
                Application.this.timer.stop();
            }
        }
```

The mentioning of `Application` before the `this` is necessary to tell Java that you mean the current `Application` instance (not the instance of the `ActionListener`.

You can also put the "actionListener" method in your `Application` directly:

```
 public void performButtonAction(int i){
      // the code from your action listener
 }
```

and then just call the method like this:

```
Start_button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
       performButtonAction(i);
    }
});
```

The only thing that is not clear to me is where your `i` is coming from (and why it is an `int` and not a `boolean` which could be easier don't you think?).

Oh, one more thing: variable names should start with a small letter `start_Button` instead of `Start_Button`. Only class names start with a capital letter. It helps you keep your code clear. Imagine you had something like this: `Application Application = new Application()` .. now what is what? :)